# Display all posts in category wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to display all posts in the category on the category archive page. 
I have used the following code, but it displays all posts from all categories.

Can someone help me please?

```
<?php 
// the query
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>

<?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<ul>

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

</ul>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a category parameter to the WP_Query array.
Check this reference in the "Category Parameters" section: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Something like this should work:

```
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'category_name' => 'your_category_slug'
));
```

Comment: I have 100 categories. Is there a way of pulling in the current category or do I need to create 100 templates?

Comment: Is your category slug or ID in the URL? If so, you could use that.

Comment: The category name will be in the URL. I want all posts to be display that are in each category on each category archive page. E.g. cat a will display all posts in cat a

Comment: If it's in the query string, you could use the function: get_query_var( 'cat', 'default' ); where 'cat' is the query string parameter name and 'default' is the default value you want to use in case 'cat' isn't found.

If it's part of the path, you will probably need to explode on / and figure out which position in the resulting array the category would be in.

Comment: This sounds all abit over my head! Thanks for your help!